# Saving project move objects

Tags: saving

I use Blender v2.83.6 on Linux Mint and I have an annoying systematic problem.
Before saving my project I inspect my work : all is in place, so I do CTRL-S.
When I re-open the file, 2 objects (always the sames) have moved.
One on Z axis and the other on Z and Y.
Each time I must reordered these objects.
I'm new with blender and I can't figure what happened. Is it a bug ?
Could you guide me ?

[My file is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ieNxYANZpQ6L3JLk8SEXxHvLo7fCkpcE/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Before saving : the 2 mics of the guitar are in place]

[image: After loading]

[image: The bases of the mics have moved and superposed. The screws have moved also and their rotation has changed]

[image: There, I rearranged these items]

Comment: You need to share more info about the objects, and some images also help. Or even you file to take a look at it

Comment: Are the objects connected each others in some mean? Parenting, modifiers, other?

Comment: No, the objects are not connected. I followed a tutorial and all objects are independents. The screws are parts of arrays. I added a link to my file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moving objects have a keyframe:when Blender load the file, it replaces the objects at the keyframed position.

[image]

Delete the keyframe. Using right click on the location:

[image]

And place again these objects where they should be.

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot. I don't know anything about keyframes, so I googled a little ;-) I don't know how I was able to add theses properties to the object.

Comment: Could simply be using the I key when over the location without noticing it.